# Adding distance threshold to pgrouting script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, distance, pgrouting, routing

I have created a loop which produces the shortest distance route between all origins and destinations within a study area. This is essentially showing routes undertaken by motorised transportation as there is no set limit of distance travelled.

I want model traffic redistribution and modal shifts to active forms of transportation.
Unlike ArcGIS for example, there is no distance threshold 'button' which calculates routes within a set distance,  i.e routes to all origins and destinations within a 2km buffer.

Is there a way to do this in pgrouting without having to use either the pgr_DrivingDistance function (I want to map routes along the road network not as an isoline) or having to filter routes by distance during the post-processing stages.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but one way to limit the possible routes is to limit the network loaded. For selecting the network data a bounding box is the most common way, because it's simple and fast, but all PostGIS spatial queries can be used as well.

Comment: Using a bounding box is definitely one way to get around it, however I was thinking in terms of what could be added to the code to do this as this will be applied at a city-level scale.

Comment: Well, with pgRouting your performance is as better as smaller your loaded network is. The network is loaded with a `SELECT` SQL statement in your pgRouting function, and there is no limit in how you query the data in order to only load the network that matters. It's very use case specific.